# Android Espresso - LinearLayout get background color from position on list

Tags: android, automated-tests, android-espresso

I have the following view on my application:
[test-application](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HNtll.png)

Is there a easy way to get a background color specific position on this list ?

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved!

My friend show me how to implement color matcher for element of list, meybe someone will need this in future so here is the solution:

```
public class ColorMatcher implements Matcher<View> {

    private final int matchColor;

    public ColorMatcher(int matchColor) {
        this.matchColor = matchColor;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean matches(Object item) {
        Context context = ((View)item).getContext();
        int c2 = context.getColor(this.matchColor);
        int c1 = ((ColorDrawable)((View)item).getBackground()).getColor();
        return c1 == c2;
    }

    @Override
    public void describeTo(Description description) {
        description.appendText("with text color: ");
    }
}
```

And now if you wanna check a color of some list element use:

```
onView(withRecyclerView(R.id.ItemFromListRecyclerView).atPosition(2))
                .check(matches(new ColorMatcher(R.color.element_defined_color)));
```